# Proof That For a Group $G$, All Automorphism of G Is Defined by The Image of The Generating Set Of G.

Tags: group-theory

Let (G,*) be a group. Let $\Phi: G \rightarrow G$ be the automorphism of $G$.

I want to show that all automorphism of $G$ is defined by the image of de generating set of $G$.

**My proof**

Let {$x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_k$} be the generating set of $G$.

By definition: $\forall y \in G$ $y=(a_1*x_1)*(a_2*x_2)*(a_3*x+3)*...*(a_k*x_k)$

Therefore, $\forall y \in G$:

$\Phi(y)$

(1) $=\Phi((a_1*x_1)*(a_2*x_2)*(a_3*x3)*...*(a_k*x_k))$

(2) $= \Phi(a_1*x_1)*\Phi(a_2*x_2)\Phi(a_3*x_3)...\Phi(a_k*x_k)$

(3) $=\Phi(a_1)*\Phi(x_1)*...*\Phi(a_k)*\Phi(x_k)$ SInce it's an isomomorphism.

Therefore In an automorphism, if {$x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_k$} is a generating set of  G,  {$\Phi(x_1),\Phi(x_2),\Phi(x_3),...,\Phi(x_k)$} is a generating set of $\Phi(G)$. Therefore all automorphisms of $G$ are defined by the generating set of G.

Comment: Why would $k$ be finite? And $\Phi(a_1x_1)=a_1\Phi(x_1)$ is wrong, you're dealing with group morphisms here. And why is there a '$+$' and a multiplication when you only have a group structure?

Comment: Your proof looks generally correct, but there are a few things you might consider.  First, in general, $G$ could have a bunch of generating sets, so I wouldn't say "the" generating set of $G$.  You also can't be sure that $k$ is finite.  Not all groups are finitely generated.

The only other thing I notice is that you should probably write your group multiplicatively, since $G$ might not be abelian.  In that notation, you'd write $y = x_{i_1}^{a_{i_1}}\cdots x_{i_k}^{a_{i_k}}$.  It's messier, but more general.  Also, $\phi(x_i^n) = \phi(x_i)^n$ by the homomorphism property.

Comment: Here, I've edited my proof it should be better

Comment: how would one find an automorphism of a cyclic group knowing this fact

Comment: Actually, more is true: Every *homomorphism* from $G$ to *any* group $H$ is determined by its image on a generating set. -  What distiurbs me the most in your proof is the abundance of "$\ldots$". To be more rigorous, you might use that every subgruop of $G$ containing your generating set is the full group. If we assume there are two homomorphisms $G\to H$ that agree on the generators, show that they on a subgroup ...